# Possible Bug in DiscretizeRegion

Tags: graphics, regions

It looks like `DiscretizeRegion` struggles with some circular arcs, in a way that seems to depend on the data types of the chosen angles. An angle specification of `{0, 2}` (integers) gives the correct result (left), but `{0, 2.}` does not (right). Can anyone confirm and/or explain? I'm running 10.3.0.0 on 64-bit Windows.

```
GraphicsRow[DiscretizeRegion[Circle[{0, 0}, 1, #]] & /@ {{0, 2}, {0, 2.}}]
```

[image: Two discretizations of the same circular arc]

Comment: Cannot reproduce on `10.4` However, it is wise not to use floating points in general.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on `10.3.1` but can reproduce on `10.2.0`. (Win 7 64-bit)

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be fixed in v11, at least.

```
GraphicsRow[DiscretizeRegion[Circle[{0, 0}, 1, #]] & /@ {{0, 2}, {0, 2.}}]
```

[image]